# How can we create a popup window for placing shortcodes in wordpress editor

Tags: wordpress, popup

Can anyone please tell me how can we create a popup window for placing shortcodes in the WordPress editor?

Comment: [Here is a plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-fiddle/) that i've developed last year, download and check the source, not a very big one but you'll find exactly what you are asking for. Also, you may search on Google for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this link to solve your problem

> http://codex.themedelta.com/how-to-create-a-popup-window-for-shortcodes-in-wordpress-editor/